# Is the "Delete this record also" option for Lookup relationships available only after getting the 'Cascade-Delete' option enabled for your org?

Tags: lookup, relationships, parent, cascadedelete

When creating a new **Lookup Relationship** on a custom object, there should be **3** behaviours to choose from when the parent object record is deleted ([according to documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.overview_of_custom_object_relationships.htm&type=5#:%7E:text=and%20permanently%20deleted.-,Delete%20this%20record%20also,-Available%20only%20if)):

- *Clear the value of this field*
- *Don’t allow deletion of the lookup record that’s part of a lookup relationship*
- ***Delete this record also***

I only see the first two options in my org. ***`Delete this record also`*** seems to be missing.

Is it because cascade-delete is not enabled, or for some other reason?

---

There is a warning in the documentation just below the ***`Delete this record also`*** option regarding *cascade-delete* and how it is disabled by default, but it is not clear if that includes the ***`Delete this record also`*** option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The warning is immediately after the *Delete this record also* option description on purpose. A *cascade delete* occurs when a parent record is deleted, and the child records are also deleted as a result. In other words, yes, you must engage Technical Support to enable Cascade Delete, which is what enables this option.